# Fill the range according to the conditions of the problem

Tags: spreadsheet

Friends, welcome!
I solve the problem with formulas, I get monstrous constructions ([see the example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q5i17MT70qWHZ2YOeGRf8g9Gl3kUZH-Y6BRj8rC4lRA/edit?usp=sharing)).

Given:
event periods are set on the Events sheet.
If a date and a duration are specified, SEQUENCE displays a series of dates.
If number and duration are specified, SEQUENCE displays 12 periods, each starting on the specified date and lasting the specified number of days
each event has its own priority (1, 2, 3)
add TIMEVALUE(“0:0”&Priority) to the displayed event dates
On the Personnel sheet of each position, you can assign events

Task:
get for each position on the sheet Positions a horizontally oriented range containing the values ​​TIMEVALUE(“0:0”&Priority) for each date of the year
when crossing dates with different priorities, display the smallest value TIMEVALUE(“0:0”&Priority)

Simply put, there are 365 days on the Jobs sheet, for each day you need to display either “0” or TIMEVALUE(“0:0”&Priority) if there is an event with a certain priority on this date. If events overlap by dates, print the minimum TIMEVALUE(“0:0”&Priority)

I made a formula that checks each assigned event - it turns out to be large and I'm not sure that the file can withstand this if the number of events is more than 50.

Please direct me to the optimal solution, how to display only the TIMEVALUE(“0:0”&Priority) values ​​corresponding to the dates in the date range on the “Positions” sheet. Thank’s

I tried to create nested formulas, but it will be inefficient with a large number of processed rows. Perhaps there are functions that I do not know about, with which you can solve the problem beautifully